# Implementing SSO in ASP.net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, single-sign-on

I am trying to develop a web application using ASP.net MVC 2. For that I want implement a single sign on ability using linked. Can anybody suggest me how can I implement that and any frameworks that I can use.

Comment: What is `linked`? Also could you provide a little more details about your scenario? Do you have a single or multiple ASP.NET applications. Are they hosted on the same domain or different domains? How is the navigation done between those applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CAS for that http://www.jasig.org/cas